# JsTree json_data plugin parent

Tags: jstree

I am working with jstree using json_data plugin, and

according to the documentation, the format is something like this.

```
{ 
    "data" : "node_title", 

    "attr" : { "id" : "node_identificator", "some-other-attribute" :                                    "attribute_value" }, 

    "state" : "closed", // or "open", defaults to "closed"

    "children" : [ /* an array of child nodes objects */ ]
}
```

I've checked jstree using "children" works fine, but haven't figured out to use "parent".

Is it just impossible to use "parent" in json_data plugin?

If someone knows the answer, please help.

Thank you in advance. Have a great day.

Comment: What version of jsTree you are using?  I don't see a plugin like that here - https://www.jstree.com/plugins/

Comment: I guess it's old version.. thanks for you comment https://old.jstree.com/documentation/json_data